# Can't change Apache2 shared folder's file

Tags: html, apache2, shared-libraries, indexof

I'd like to change the page that shows what files I've uploaded. I never found the editable file. Can it be changed at all?? I have read a bunch article about this problem but I haven't found the solution.

I am talking about this page: [Index of /--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdoUC.png)

Here is my shared folder: [Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMqel.png)

Comment: But where is the index file and what it's name? This is what I am looking for.

Comment: Oh I found the file. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the index file (probably: `index.html` or `index.php`) or add one yourself, if it does not exist yet. You can use `.htaccess` for example, if the directory or files inside should be access protected. You can also redirect the user when he is accessing the directory or a file inside.

The images that you have provided show the fallback display of a directory for apache.